# Find Rostopic dataType cpp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am writing a publisher/subscriber for a ros topic, but i would like to find the dataType of the topic programatically (instead of from rostopic info) in the code. Is there a way to query the topic info in c++?
A sample code would be much appreciated.
thanks
sid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49254/find-rostopic-datatype-cpp/) by [siddahuja](https://answers.ros.org/users/794/siddahuja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the [Master/Slave](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_API) using xmlrpc is used for that. There is some python sample code. You should be able to use that same functionality in C++.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1